# UITableView cell's drop shadow changes position after table scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have some strange things happening. I am applying a drop shadow to a table cell using:

```
statsTableCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
statsTableCell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1)
statsTableCell.layer.shadowRadius = 3
statsTableCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

This applies the drop shadow to the bottom of the table cell. If the cell scrolls off the top of the screen, when it comes back I can see 2 drop shadows. Both top and bottom.

I have used the code above in other places in the app on uiviews without the same issues.

I only want the shadow to be applied to the bottom of the cell but can't work out why this is only happening on table cells.

In fact, if the table cell scrolls completely out of view and then back in, it swaps the position of the drop shadow depending on the scroll direction. If I scroll down the shadow applies to the top, if I scroll up, it applies to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `statsTableCell.layer.masksToBounds=false`.